# Benefits of a RAID BBU in addition to a double UPS + PS system

Tags: raid, cache, ups, write, bbu

Today I roughly measured the benefits of enabling write-back on the RAID controller on a server at work. It got no RAID battery-backup-unit (BBU) so the write-cache is currently disabled. As the server is not used to capacity (by far), the results in most test were spectacular, e.g.:

- Database CRUD: before 35s, after 4s
- Saving a 1MB Excel file: before: 20s (!), after: 0.5s

Of course having a BBU is always recommended, but what are the main benefits of installing a BBU to a system, which got redundant power supplies and is attached to UPSs? Does this depend on the type of the system (database, file, terminal)?

What is a realistic fail scenario which could be prevented by a BBU?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RAID battery back-up protects you from:

- Building power failures (not as big an issue with dual-UPS)
- PSU Failures (not as big an issue with dual-PS)
- Utility failures (Do you have a generator? What happens when your UPS runs flat?)
- Generator failures (I've seen these happen; again: What happens when your UPS runs flat?)
- Breaker trips (single if you only have one power leg; double less likely)
- Fat Feet tripping over your power cords
- "Oops, I pulled the wrong breaker!"
- "Oops, dropped my screwdriver onto the power bus!"

*etc. etc. etc.*

How likely any of these are in your environment is something only you can determine. I have seen every single one of them in a production scenario though, so they're all possible :)

Comment: haha @ Ooops, dropped my screwdriver onto the power bus! ... I would also add transfer switch blowing up when it tries to switch over or UPS batteries catching on fire ... i've seen all of the above as well.

Comment: Or the Emergency Power Off feature of your fire-system dropping power from the entire room for safety reasons. I haven't seen an EPO actually trigger, but I've been in datacenters that had them.

Comment: Good point on the EPO -- I've been in a lot of datacenters that have them but never been (un)fortunate enough to see one go off.  (I've also never seen the UPS batteries or ATS blow up/catch fire, but I have a wonderful story about a generator and 5-foot flames from the exhaust... :)

Answer (score 4):

how about ugly OS crash because of something... bug in drivers, bug in kernel of the os?

they happen rarely but still.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, unless the server is receiving power from different PDUs, I can't really consider redundant power supplies a complete solution.

The write cache does not commit data instantly to the disk, so if there is a power failure you will lose all the data in the cache without a BBU.